# Output Dates in Celery Crontab Schedule to Django Template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, cron, celery

I'm using Celery for my Django project and I've scheduled some crontab tasks to send emails out to users at certain times. I need to output a schedule in an HTML/Django template that shows the dates that users can expect the emails to go out on. My crontab schedule looks like this for Celery:

```
import os
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

app = Celery("myapp")
app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print("Request: {0!r}".format(self.request))

first_monday_april_to_july = crontab(
    minute=15, hour=6, day_of_week="monday", day_of_month="1-7", month_of_year="4,5,6,7"
)
august_every_monday_first_two_weeks = crontab(
    minute=15, hour=6, day_of_week="monday", day_of_month="1-14", month_of_year="8"
)
august_weekdays_second_two_weeks = crontab(
    minute=15, hour=6, day_of_week="mon-fri", day_of_month="15-31", month_of_year="8"
)

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    "report1": {
        "task": "email_report",
        "schedule": first_monday_april_to_july,
    },
    "report2": {
        "task": "email_report",
        "schedule": august_every_monday_first_two_weeks,
    },
    "report3": {
        "task": "email_report",
        "schedule": august_weekdays_second_two_weeks,
}
```

I was hoping to be able to grab all of the dates that the emails will be sent on from these tasks and save them into a list in the view and then send it to the template to be displayed in a table. Is something like this possible? I'm not having any luck finding a way to do this so far.

Comment: Do you mean, that you need to calculate what next execution date will be?

Comment: meybe [this package](https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat) can help you. `PeriodicTask` task model defined in this django app contains info about periodic celery tasks. You can pass queryset of this model to context and use in template.

Comment: @VictorErmakov Yes, it would need to show all of the execution dates for the tasks.

Comment: I think, that you need to get this package https://github.com/kiorky/croniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a function to grab all of the dates from the tasks and then append them all to a schedule list and then passed that through the view to the template to be output in a table. It looks like this:

```
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
from .celery import (
    first_monday_april_to_july,
    august_every_monday_first_two_weeks,
    august_weekdays_second_two_weeks,
)


def get_schedule_due_dates(schedule, last_date=datetime.now().date().replace(month=12, day=31)):
    start_date = datetime.now()
    end_date = datetime.combine(last_date, datetime.max.time())
    schedules = []
    while start_date <= end_date:
        next_due_schedule = schedule.remaining_estimate(start_date)
        due_date = datetime.now() + next_due_schedule
        if due_date <= end_date:
            schedules.append(due_date)
        else:
            break
        start_date = due_date + timedelta(days=1)
    return schedules


def report_schedule(request):
    schedules = []
    schedules.extend(get_schedule_due_dates(first_monday_april_to_july))
    schedules.extend(get_schedule_due_dates(august_every_monday_first_two_weeks))
    schedules.extend(get_schedule_due_dates(august_weekdays_second_two_weeks))
    return render(
        request,
        "reports/report_schedule.html",
        {"schedules": sorted(schedules)},
    )
```